# Not able to interact via SSH from a JAVA program

Tags: java, linux, ssh

I am doing SSH with my linux server via a java program , I am able to execute the commands like shell scripts. But the problem is whenever I am executing a particular shell script it is giving an option to select between yes or no , now from my java console I am selecting yes but this is not actually interacting with the linux server. How to do this job via a java programming? if you have any code spake please share . I am shairing my code for doing the SSH.

```
    String arr1[]=new String[arr.length];
    ReadConfig rc=new ReadConfig();
    rc.readConfig();
    hostname=rc.hostname;
    username=rc.username;
    password=rc.password;
    for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
    {
        arr1[i]= arr[i];
        System.out.println("the array value "+arr1[i]+" "+i);
    }

    try{
         String com=arr1[5].toString().trim();
         System.out.println("  "+com);
        /* Create a connection instance */

        conn = new Connection(hostname);

        /* Now connect */
                conn.connect();


                /* Authenticate.
         * If you get an IOException saying something like
         * "Authentication method password not supported by the server at this stage."
         * then please check the FAQ.
         */

            boolean isAuthenticated = conn.authenticateWithPassword(username, password);


                if (isAuthenticated == false)
                    throw new IOException("Authentication failed.");

                /* Create a session */

                sess = conn.openSession();
               try{
                  sess.execCommand(com);


                //obj.append("Pass");
               }catch(Exception e){


                   //obj.append("Fail");
               }
                //Session sess1 = conn.openSession();
                System.out.println("Here is some information about the remote host:");
                InputStream stdout = new StreamGobbler(sess.getStdout());
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stdout));

                while (true)
                {
                    String line = br.readLine();
                    if (line == null)
                        break;
                    System.out.println(line);
                }
                /* Show exit status, if available (otherwise "null") */

                System.out.println("ExitCode: " + sess.getExitStatus());

    }catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }finally{
        /* Close this session */
    //obj.close();
        sess.close();
        /* Close the connection */

        conn.close();
    }
```

Comment: Looks like you are using Ganymed-SSH2. Whatever it is you should say so in the question. But if the shell script does something so that it gets input from the console rather than stdin there is really nothing you can do about it.

Comment: yes I am using ganymade ssh but how to make it interactive with the linux server?

Answer (score 1):

You are not writing anything to the input stream. Just typing in the java console doesn't do anything at all.

Create a PrintWriter for the sessions stdin-OutputStream:

Then you can `out.println("y")` if you need to. If you need interactivity using the java-console, you need to read from System.in and send that to your outputstream.

```
PrintWriter out = createPW(new OutputStreamWriter(sess.getStdin()), true);
```

Here's a half-decent way of creating a PrintWriter with a suitable line separator character.

```
public static PrintWriter createPrintWriter(OutputStreamWriter out, boolean autoflush) {
    Properties props = System.getProperties();
    synchronized (props) {
        Object old = null;
        try {
            old = props.setProperty("line.separator", "\n");
            return new PrintWriter(out, autoflush);
        } finally {
            if (old != null) {
                props.put("line.separator", old);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A warning though. It's rather tricky to work with ganymede and ssh, unix sessions etc, you really need to know a little about everything.

Answer (score -2):

you can use "yes" command. Pipe output from Yes into the next command

```
yes | apt-get install some_software
```

Comment: Sorry but not getting your idea.. please give the require cod efor this

Comment: prefix "yes | " to all your command strings. yes command outputs a "y" and with | we can send this output as an input to the next command. so when ever u execute a command and it waits for input, it gets from yes command. 

it might work.

Comment: Sorry, it wont work since you is not using a shell, but rather is executing a command. Starting a shell opens up a whole other can of worms. The simplest way is probably to write a shellscript that does what you want, and the execute *that* using ssh.)